# Yammer REST API CORS error: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource

Tags: yammer

We are working with REST APIs of Yammer and sometimes we are getting below exceptions and not able to complete requests.

[image]

**Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/users/followed_by/XXX.json?&_=XXX. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.**

we added web url to javascript origins too. It is observed in IE and Firefox too.

@Yammer team: can you please check. Thanks.